# Android list view not showing data when height is wrap_content

Tags: android, listview

I have issue with the list view item showing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/view_top_tab_bar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/black_bold_20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_common"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/news_and_offers" />

    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/News_sv_PullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="3dip"
        android:paddingRight="3dip"
        ptr:ptrAnimationStyle="flip"
        ptr:ptrMode="pullFromStart" >
    </com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I set the `height` of the `ListView` to `warp_content` , the list doesn't show a single row.

I have set all element `height` to `wrap_content` in `list_row_item.xml` file.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: it because warp_content has no sens for scrollable

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_top_tab_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            style="@style/black_bold_20"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_common"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/news_and_offers" />

        <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
            xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/News_sv_PullToRefresh"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="3dip"
            android:paddingRight="3dip"
            ptr:ptrAnimationStyle="flip"
            ptr:ptrMode="pullFromStart" >
        </com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not working. Basically I want to give a white color background to textview and list item. If I give white background to linearlayout , it is coming on full screen so I want to wrap_content the textview and pullrefreshlistview so only that portion come white in which I have the data. I hope it is clear now what I am looking.